# Replace only where changed with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am in a situation where I need to replace the contents of a `<head>` element, without replacing the content with what's already there.

My `<head>` contains the CSS links, the Meta and the title. These are updated from an ajax call, containing the html, which javascript then replaces it with.

My issue is that I get a FOUC because it is also replacing the already loaded CSS, with that CSS. Is there anyway to have it NOT replace the CSS because it's already there?

My code:

```
var headHTML; // This gets updated on the ajax call
$('head').html(headHTML);
```

Comment: This seems like a horrible idea, and if you have to replace everything in the head section, you probably failed horribly at something else!

Comment: Well then you should give me a suggestion on a better approach then. I still need to modify the meta and title with the ajax calls.

Comment: Why? Anyway, `document.title = 'something else'` is the way to go

Comment: That's only the title, what about the meta tags?

Comment: `document.querySelector('meta[name=keywords]')` <- this is just basic stuff ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I agree with the comments, and think that there is a better way to do this. here's something you can do to make it work.

Elements inside the `<head>` can also be selected using jquery. So you can individually change the title and meta like

```
$('head title').html('your text here');
$('head meta').attr('set it here');
```